# API Connection To Sandbox URL

Tags: rest-api, community, api

I have a vendor that is trying to establish an API connection to our sandbox.  Is this the correct URL for sandbox? https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - for sandbox orgs, you take the standard endpoints and replace `login.salesforce.com` with `test.salesforce.com`. More in [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm).